# Text-to-Speech engine for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, text-to-speech

These days I came into the programming for Windows Phone. So, I can't find the TTS (Text-to-Speech) engine. Is anybody knows this one?

Answer (score 0):

My library does text-to-speech.
[Click here](http://ttsforwindowsphone7.codeplex.com)

I haven't implemented speech-to-text yet, but might do so soon.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this one . [Project Hawaii SDK for Windows Phone](http://www.ginktage.com/2012/08/project-hawaii-sdk-for-windows-phone/) . Its mentioned that it has Text-to-Speech service . Have to give a try though :)